# Rigging - pose mode is squanched up

Tags: animation, rigging

I downloaded a rigged character in a blend file here:
http://cdn.digitaltutors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DT_Puppet_Rig.zip

When I open it in blender it is fine in armature rest position, but the pose position is all squashed up and unusable.

Can anyone give any hints about what I'm doing wrong. I tried to select all and clear pose transforms but no luck.

thanks for any help,
Andreas.

Comment: When I open this file it works fine.

Comment: Thank you Jerryno for checking this for me. I tried several versions of Blender, but it is always the same problem - in Pose mode the arms and legs of the character disappear and his feet are coming out of his pelvis. Could it be my preferences are corrupted? I'l get out my old laptop and try it on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! The hint was an error warning - "autorun disabled!" Blender wasn't running a script. Press Ctrl + Alt + U, then head over to File and enable Auto Run Python Scripts. Now all works well. The automatic running of python scripts has been disabled since version 2.6.